# Spring Boot - OAuth2 - Scope Limit Resources at the Field Level

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Is there an annotation or DI based approach for implementing resource field level filtering based on oauth2 scope in Spring?

We have a spring boot based resource server that has oauth2 scope protected endpoints. This works fine to scope protect endpoints, however we want to be able to filter sensitive information from the resources we expose based on scope. E.g. I only want to expose last 4 of a person's SSN when the client scope allows it.

So far the only way I've found to do this on the resource server is like this:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods expressionMethods = new OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods(authentication);

boolean hasScope = expressionMethods.hasScope("xyz.read");

if(hasScope) {
  resource.setSsn(entity.getSsn());   
}
```

So when scope "xyz.read" is not present the resource will look like this:

```
{
  "name": "blah"
}
```

But when scope "xyz.read" is present the resource will look like this:

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "ssn": "123-45-2347"
}
```

Having to reach out and grab the authentication object from the security context holder and construct a new OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods every time we want to check scope seems like we're missing something. However as this is a 'pure' OAuth2 resource server we've not discovered a better way to accomplish this.

This is what our resource server configuration looks like (and it does work fine):

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('xyz.read')");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("resource-id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the @JsonView annotation, where the view names reflect authentication or access levels. Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation.

The goal: when the object is serialized, the view will dictate which fields should be shown/serialized.